# Improving the SQL commands to display preceding and following values in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, alphabetical

With the two following SQL commands I seek 15 headwords that preceding the displayed headword and 15 headwords that following the headwords in alphabetical order.

The keyword column is indexed. The time of execution is stated.

Is there quicker or better solution to find several preceding and following values in large alphabetical list?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         `keyword`, `num_keyword`,`stem`, `gram_1_word_group` 
     FROM 
         `ds_1_headword` 
     WHERE 
         `keyword` COLLATE `utf8_icelandic_ci` <= 'Patagónía' 
     ORDER BY 
         `keyword` COLLATE `utf8_icelandic_ci` DESC, `num_keyword` 
     LIMIT 15) AS `table`
ORDER BY 
    `keyword` COLLATE `utf8_icelandic_ci` ASC, `num_keyword
```

5.4222950935364

```
 SELECT `keyword`, `num_keyword`,`stem`, `gram_1_word_group` 
 FROM `ds_1_headword` 
 WHERE `keyword` COLLATE `utf8_icelandic_ci` > 'Patagónía'
 ORDER BY `keyword` COLLATE `utf8_icelandic_ci` ASC, `num_keyword` limit 15
```

7.3961861133575

If I am not mistaken, when the column is in the same collation as in the query, this is redundant information and can be deleted, and hopefully also makes it faster.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT `keyword`, `num_keyword`,`stem`, `gram_1_word_group` 
    FROM `ds_1_headword` 
    WHERE `keyword` <= 'Patagónía' 
    ORDER BY `keyword` desc, `num_keyword` limit 15) AS `table`
    ORDER by `keyword` ASC, `num_keyword
```

<5.4222950935364

```
 SELECT `keyword`, `num_keyword`,`stem`, `gram_1_word_group` 
 FROM `ds_1_headword` 
 WHERE `keyword` > 'Patagónía'
 ORDER BY `keyword` ASC, `num_keyword` limit 15
```

<7.3961861133575

**Update**
Eplain of 1. query

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    15  Using filesort
2   DERIVED     ds_1_headword   range   keyword     keyword     302     NULL    23205   Using where
```

Explain of 2. query

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  ds_1_headword   range   keyword     keyword     302     NULL    30646   Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting the question.

Comment: can you post sample data and expected results?  your query currently would just get the 15 headwords "immediately preceding" and "immediately following" the string "Patagonia".  Is 2 x 15 = 30 records all you want at a time, and you're wondering why it takes 5 and 7 seconds?

Comment: Exactly, sample data is problem - I search in 53000 records each time the new headword is displayed (new alphabetical list with 15 preceding and 15 following headwords is displayed too). Yes, the queries have to take less time.

Comment: If the entire list is only 53K rows, you should let the application load in ALL of them and do this in the memory of the application - it should be lightning fast. In addition, it seems like your database is not optimized very well **at all** to this type of query, if it takes 5 seconds.  You should fix the database if you can; otherwise, do one big `SELECT ` in the application and manage the list of 53000 in whatever language the app uses, rather than this poor-performing mysql query.  Are you in a position to fix the db, or an app developer, or both?

Comment: let me know if my comment is getting towards an answer for you, and I'll be happy to post it that way :)

Comment: Ok, yes, the comments are helpful :). I am in position to do both. I guess the table is not optimized very well. It is interesting idea to load all data at once - can you direct me in an answer where to store the data in php and how to reuse them effectively?

Comment: Please add, add SlimsGhost suggested, the `explain`-output of your query (write `explain ` directly infront of it and post the result). Your queries should not take 7 seconds if you have the right index (and for 50k rows, actually even if you don't have). And you are right, a wrong collate will slow your query down (because it will prevent the use of indexes).

Comment: I have added output of explain queries from phpmyadmin (hope it is enough). The time of the query is generally lower (about 0.2-0.4s). Still those queries take most of the time of all queries.

Comment: @chejnik, i noticed your update (and bounty).  From the explain plan, it looks like you do have a database index on the `keyword` column. And from your comment, it looks like you have reduced the time by more than 20x (from 5-7s down to 0.2-0.4s). This is a very big improvement!  It is also about what I would guess is "pretty good" performance.  That is certainly a response time (<1s) that I have built many successful applications around.  What exactly do you need for you to consider this question answered? I will try to get you to that point if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for speed, declare the column `keyword` to be `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATION utf8_icelandic_ci`.

By stating a different collation in the query, no index can be used, so you are scanning the entire table.

For getting the 15 rows before and after a given word (plus the given row), this is optimal:

```
( SELECT `keyword`, `num_keyword`,`stem`, `gram_1_word_group` 
       FROM ds_1_headword
       WHERE keyword <  'Patagónía'
       ORDER BY keyword DESC LIMIT 15 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT `keyword`, `num_keyword`,`stem`, `gram_1_word_group` 
       FROM ds_1_headword
       WHERE keyword >= 'Patagónía'
       ORDER BY keyword ASC  LIMIT 16 )
ORDER BY keyword;   -- assuming you want the result sorted
```

MariaDB 10.0.2 has "Windowing functions, which can do a similar thing without the `UNION`, probably even more efficiently.

If you need to order the *same* column by a variety of Collations, you are out of luck.  Rethink the schema (add more columns?) and/or the requirements (not require multiple collations?).

Comment: I use the same collation, fortunately. I will reward this answer when the system allows me. It is very fast indeed - combining both commands into one and not using the utf8_icelandic_ci in queries when the column is already in this collation. The query time is 0.013284921646118 !!! Thank you.

Comment: Correction:  MariaDB 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the data retrieval faster, here are a couple of broad topics that should start you in the right direction:

1. Is the database running on a machine that is "powerful enough"? For a 53K row table to be lightning fast, even a machine with 1 core and 4GB of RAM would be "powerful enough" unless the machine is swamped with other workloads.
2. If the machine is "powerful enough", then you should look at the mysql table and check the **execution plan** (look that up if needed). And one very common thing you need to do is check that there is an **INDEX** on the column that you are searching/sorting on (`keyword` in your case). [Here's a link on indexes in mysql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)
3. If making the database faster becomes difficult, you can just pull **ALL** the data into PHP, and if the machine executing PHP is "powerful enough", a script should be able to manage 53K values and pull the "15 before, 15 after" in a matter of milliseconds, rather than seconds.  As far as how you do this in PHP, here's an example of a [PHP Tutorial page for SELECTing from a table](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

Hope this gets you started on the right path.  If you still need help, just ask!

Comment: The issue was caused by overload of hosting database server - now the time is 0.2039909362793. Anyway I will continue to examine your suggestions and will leave the question till tomorrow. Subquestion in which variable you would store the 53000 results in php?

Comment: Good! The time of 0.2 seconds makes much more sense.  I still recommend you to put it in application memory, as long as the size is not too big. If it is just list of 53K words (or if you need to use multiple columns from 53K rows), and each row was made up of 50 bytes for the keyword and 50 bytes of other stuff, that would only require something like 53K x 100 = 5.3 MB, which is no prob for a system with 4GB of memory or more. A PHP "list" object or even an array would allow you to hold the list of words, sort them alphabetically, and retrieve the 15 before/after words with no problem.

Comment: if this answer helped you, can you mark it as the Answer?

Comment: After new page is refreshed the array variable is empty. I am not sure, if I explain it well. Each time the headword is displayed, the page is reloaded and new list of words is displayed.

Comment: If you are showing this data on a web page, which I can only guess at since you didn't specify, then you know that every time the page is "refreshed" either the server is going to have to re-execute your PHP script and repopulate the array, and/or you have to handle it in the client browser with Javascript.  I think your question has changed enough that you should post it as a new one if you need more help. Good luck! :)